Pinescript code for finding highs and lows of the first 10 days of January and March of the current year. But March starts from 4th rather than 1st
I wrote a code on Pinescript to find the highest and lowest point of the first 10 days of January and March seperately for the current year. So the highest and lowest points of first 10 days of January are plotted, and highest and lowest points of first 10 days of March are plotted seperately. Somehow, January works but with March, high and low lines start from the 4th of March in daily bars. Whereas 1st of March was Friday and the markets were open so the line should start from there and also consider that day too and continue from that point. Or when I change the month to something else, it starts from 2nd or 3rd sometimes rather than starting from 1st even if it's a working day and the markets are open. In addition, when I use hourly bars, then the start day is correct but this time the starting time is later than the market opening hour.  Can someone help me what is my mistake here and how can I fix it? I'm a newbie and I would appreciate any kind of support. Thank you all in advance.
//@version=4
study("First 10 Days of January and March", overlay=true)

// Get the current year
currentYear = year(timenow)

// Finding the highest and lowest values of the first 10 days of January
var float januaryHighest = na
var float januaryLowest = na

if (month == 01 and dayofmonth >= 1 and dayofmonth <= 10 and year == currentYear)
    if (na(januaryHighest) or high > januaryHighest)
        januaryHighest := high
    if (na(januaryLowest) or low < januaryLowest)
        januaryLowest := low

// Finding the highest and lowest values of the first 10 days of March
var float marchHighest = na
var float marchLowest = na

if (month == 03 and dayofmonth >= 1 and dayofmonth <= 10 and year == currentYear)
    if (na(marchHighest) or high > marchHighest)
        marchHighest := high
    if (na(marchLowest) or low < marchLowest)
        marchLowest := low

// Plotting
plot(januaryHighest, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, title="January Highest")
plot(januaryLowest, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, title="January Lowest")
plot(marchHighest, color=color.blue, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, title="March Highest")
plot(marchLowest, color=color.orange, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2, title="March Lowest")

// Adding labels
label.new(bar_index, januaryHighest, tostring(januaryHighest), color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_circle, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
label.new(bar_index, januaryLowest, tostring(januaryLowest), color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_circle, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
label.new(bar_index, marchHighest, tostring(marchHighest), color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_circle, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
label.new(bar_index, marchLowest, tostring(marchLowest), color=color.orange, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_circle, yloc=yloc.belowbar)

// As a result of this code I've written, dotted lines for March start from the 4th of March and it is similar with other months I tried also. Even if the day is right, then the starting hour of the dotted line is not correct. I would appreciate any help to fix it.

You haven't added any info on what symbol you try to trade. Different markets have different opening times. Also, if you are at it now, don't write code in Pine V4 but switch to V5.
